# SAS character to numeric with varying decimal input

Tags: sas

In SAS, I am trying to convert a character value to numeric with 2 decimal points? It works most of the time except when I get an input value with no decimals. For example:

myvar_old
26.30
75
33.12

after I convert I am getting:

myvar
26.30
0.75
33.12

How do I get 75.00 instead?

I tried the following with no success:
myvar = INPUT(myvar_old,DOLLAR12.2);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data have;
input myvar_old $;
datalines;
26.30 
75    
33.12 
;

data want;
   set have;
   myvar = input(myvar_old, 8.);
   format myvar 8.2;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

SAS is just doing what you asked it to do.  When you include a number for the decimal places on an INFORMAT you are telling SAS where to place the implied decimal point for strings that do not have one. So for example if you use 12.2 as the total width and number of decimal places on an informat it means that any string without a period will be divided by 100 (10**2) so that there are two decimal places.  This feature is there to support reading files where the decimal place is omitted on purpose to save a character.

If you want SAS to ignore dollar signs and commas in the source strings you should use the COMMA informat. The DOLLAR informat is just an alias for the COMMA informat.

Also when using the INPUT() function there is no need to worry about the width of the informat used.  You can use a width that is larger than the length of the string being read without any error.  So in most cases it is best to just use the maximum width that the particular informat supports.

```
myvar = input(myvar_old,32.);
```

If you want the value to display with 2 decimal places then attach a FORMAT to the variable.  If you also want thousand separators then use the COMMA format. If you also want it to display a dollar sign then use the DOLLAR format.

```
format myvar dollar12.2 ;
```

If you used 2 for the number of decimal places because you want the value ROUNDED to ONLY two decimal places you will have to do that AFTER you have converted the string into a number.

```
myvar = round(input(myvar_old,32.),0.01);
```